# XWİKİ AppWithinMinutes

Tags: xwiki

I am developing an inventory management system. I am using AppWithinMinutes (AWM). Only administrator can add, edit and delete. In this system, the user name is entered in the user field. Other fields are entering other information. How can users see only their own children when they log in to xwiki with their own name? And how can not he see the other kids?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement and [EventListener](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/WritingEventListenerTutorial/) in your application so that, whenever an entry in your application is created, an XWikiRights object is added to the page to allow `view` access only to the user that created it and some admin group (that is allowed to see all the entries of all the users).

Note that it would be recommended to implement your EventListener as a [WikiComponent](https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/WikiComponent%20Module) so that it is automatically registered when your XWiki instance is restarted.